# React <textarea> component fails to validate in Chrome when value is passed in through value prop

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, validation, textarea

I stumbled onto this issue when using Material-UI's TextField component. When passing the multiline prop on TextField, the component is set to `<textarea>`, and when passing the multiline and minlength prop at the same time, minlength fails to validate. I have narrowed this problem down to the `<textarea>` element, on which the same problem occurs when passing value in through the "value" prop, BUT this only happens in Chrome and Edge, not FireFox. The minlength prop also does validate when value is passed in as children of the `<textarea>`.

Here is an example that fails to validate:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <textarea minLength={5} value={textareaValue} onChange={handleTextareaChange} />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is the validation object readout for a test in which I submit less than 5 characters, which should fail validation:

```
{
    badInput: false,
    customError: false,
    patternMismatch: false,
    rangeOverflow: false,
    rangeUnderflow: false,
    stepMismatch: false,
    tooLong: false,
    tooShort: false,
    typeMismatch: false,
    valid: true,
    valueMissing: false
}
```

In [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), it says "`<textarea>` does not support the value attribute." But in [this React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/textarea) it says "You can make a text area controlled by passing a value prop".

Has anyone else had this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Apologies however `minLength` property on textarea does not work at all. Official docs from W3C don't even mention that this prop exists. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: @kinduser Thanks for your response! However, when I test this, the `<textarea>` `minLength` prop does validate correctly in Firefox. It also works in any browser when the value is passed in as the child of `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

> It also works in any browser when the value is passed in as the child of `<textarea>`.

The `minLength` property seems to work fine but **only if** your `textarea` is  *uncontrolled* (does not have `value` nor `onChange` props). This is a downside but maybe in your particular case maybe this is what you are looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-ardinghelli-rc5f63?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea minLength="5" />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```